# How to delete from vector using ifelse condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a vector a with values (1,2,3,4) and another vector b with values (1,1,0,1). Using the elements in b as a flag, I want to remove the vector elements from A at the same positions where 0 is found in element b.

```
  a <- c(1,2,3,4)
  b <- c(1,1,0,1)
     for(i in 1:length(b))
  {
    if(b[i] == 0)
    {
      a <- a[-i]
    }
  }
```

I get the desired output

> a
>   [1] 1 2 4

But using ifelse, I do not get the output as required.

```
    a <- c(1,2,3,4)
  b <- c(1,1,0,1)
    for(i in 1:length(b))
    {
      a <- ifelse(b[i] == 0,a[-i],a)
    }
```

Output:

> a
>   [1] 1

How to use ifelse in such situations?

Answer (score 5):

I think `ifelse` isn't the correct function here since `ifelse` gives output of same length as input and we want to subset values here. You don't need a loop as well. You can directly do

```
a[b != 0]
#[1] 1 2 4
```

**data**

```
a <- 1:4
b <- c(1, 1, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option could be:

```
a[as.logical(b)]

[1] 1 2 4
```

Comment: @chinsoon12 been thinking about it, but decided not to post it as it may be too tricky :D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `ifelse`, you can use the following code

```
na.omit(ifelse(b==0,NA,a))
```

such that

```
> na.omit(ifelse(b==0,NA,a))
[1] 1 2 4
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 3
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use double negation

```
a[!!b]
#[1] 1 2 4
```

#### data

```
a <- 1:4  
b <- c(1, 1, 0, 1)
```